# Returns an object list in a get Spring Boot request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api

I created a Spring service to return a list of notifications to the Front End. However, to make handling the return list easier, I needed to change the return object. But I don't know how to do this.

Currently the return list looks like this:

```html
[
    {
        "id": 24,
        "titulo": "Titulo da Notificacao",
        "mensagem": "Mensagem da Notificacao",
        "dataCriacao": "2021-07-23 17:00:25.244-03",
        "dataModificacao": null,
        "status": true
    },
    {
        "id": 25,
        "titulo": "Titulo da Notificacao 2",
        "mensagem": "Mensagem da Notificacao 2",
        "dataCriacao": "2021-07-23 17:00:25.244-03",
        "dataModificacao": null,
        "status": true
    }
]
```

I need the feedback to be like this:

```html
{
  "notificacoes":
    [
      {
          "id": 24,
          "titulo": "Titulo da Notificacao",
          "mensagem": "Mensagem da Notificacao",
          "dataCriacao": "2021-07-23 17:00:25.244-03",
          "dataModificacao": null,
          "status": true
      },
      {
          "id": 25,
          "titulo": "Titulo da Notificacao 2",
          "mensagem": "Mensagem da Notificacao 2",
          "dataCriacao": "2021-07-23 17:00:25.244-03",
          "dataModificacao": null,
          "status": true
      }
    ]
}
```

```html
    @RequestMapping(value = "/status/{status}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
    public List<?> findAllByStatus(@PathVariable("status") Boolean status) {
        return service.findAllByStatus(status);
    }
```

Can anyone help me? I thought about creating a Notifications object that contains a Notification List. But I think there is a simpler way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

How about using a map ?

This would allow you to set the key "notificacoes" and reuse the method you currently have, providing a list of notifications.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/status/{status}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
public Map<String, List<Notification>> findAllByStatus(@PathVariable("status") Boolean status) {
        Map<String, List<Notification>> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("notificacoes",  service.getNotifications());
        return response;
    }
```